# Excel VBA - Explicitly Reference Current Application Instance

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

The following code is a function that takes as inputs the name of a target workbook to check if is already open as well as the excel application instance in which it may be open.  The function will then cycle thru the open workbooks in that application instance.  If the target workbook is open, then the workbook object is returned.  If not already open, the target workbook is opened and then returned.

I am attempting to treat the "app" argument as an optional input, as normally there will only be one Excel instance.  However, with the following format, I get the following compile error:  "Constant expression required."

```
Function wbOpen(currFile, Optional app As Application = Application) As Workbook

    Dim oWB As Workbook

    currFile = StrConv(currFile, vbLowerCase)

    For Each oWB In app.Workbooks

        oWBName = StrConv(oWB.name, vbLowerCase)
        If oWBName = currFile Then

            fileOpen = True
            Exit For

        End If

    Next oWB

    If Not fileOpen Then Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(currFile)

    Set wbOpen = oWB

End Function
```

Whenever I'm referencing the current Application within a method, I can simply write "Application.[method or property]".

How do I explicitly reference the active Excel application instance so that I can have it as a default value for the "app" argument?

If possible, I'd prefer to not have "app" have no default value and then check if the value is nil in code.

Comment: If this is not a VB Script, if it is a function/macro from within Excel, you don't need to reference the active excel application, it is already implied in Application no mater what macro you run. Meaning that you can use Application.Workbooks.Count to get all the workbooks in the current instance, and you can use that on any Subfunction/Function without the need of a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to return an object that requires a constant expression check if the expression is nothing within the code and then set it there  (I usually do this when returning the correct workbook as an optional workbook - i.e. `ThisWorkbook`).

I'm not sure of the feasibility of returning the application like that though - I've never tried it.

```
Public Function wbOpen(currFile As String, Optional app As Application) As Workbook

    Dim oWB As Workbook

    If app Is Nothing Then
        Set app = Application
    End If

    currFile = StrConv(currFile, vbLowerCase)

    For Each oWB In app.Workbooks

        oWBName = StrConv(oWB.Name, vbLowerCase)
        If oWBName = currFile Then

            fileOpen = True
            Exit For

        End If

    Next oWB

    If Not fileOpen Then Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(currFile)

    Set wbOpen = oWB

End Function
```

> If possible, I'd prefer to not have "app" have no default value and
>   then check if the value is nil in code.

...I don't know if there's any other way.

Comment: You might have the same problem as OP in your UDF. UDF checks if **`fileOpen`** is not **TRUE**, then attempts to open the workbook and assign that as a returning workbook. But as **`fileOpen`** is never set to `FALSE`, when it gets to that statement, and workbook was not found in the opened workbooks, **`fileOpen`** will not have a value so might not ever go into that condition. Which in turn means that you are just returning a workbook object which isn't pointing to any workbook. I might be wrong but might be worth a check

Comment: @Zac That is true.  I didn't check the rest of the code - just added the relevant bit, but a boolean variable does default to FALSE when first declared... but the OP isn't using Option Explicit so isn't declaring the variable so it's first created on that line as TRUE.. dammit, use **Option Explicit**.  Makes life so much easier. :)

Comment: Yup :). like you mentioned, all of this goes away if **Option Explicit** is used

Comment: Thanks.  Branching aside, I see what Darren is intending.  It may be that the only way is to check for nil and set app to Application inside the function if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have use other excel apps to process data in background and then before exit I close all other instances. My the code help some one.

```
Public Sub CloseAllOtherExcel()
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim lngMyHandle As Long
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    lngMyHandle = Application.hwnd

    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Do While TypeName(objExcel) = "Application"
        If objExcel.hwnd <> lngMyHandle Then
            Debug.Print "found another Excel instance: " & _
                objExcel.hWndExcelApp
            obExcel.Quit acQuitSaveNone
        Else
            Debug.Print "found myself"
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Loop

'ExitHere
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ") in procedure CloseAllOtherExcel"
    MsgBox strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```